# Is it possible show blog data(pdf) from database with other result(string)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, oracle

I am showing(Not downloading) pdf file from my database as **blob** using **header("Content-type:application/pdf")**; , and now I want to show some string results also with this pdf file.is it possible?Iam showing pdf in iframe.

Comment: in the same result page? No, not possible. if you're outputting a pdf, then the ONLY thing you can output is that pdf. you can't output multiple media types at the same time

Comment: How do you envision this? Open two tabs, one for pdf and another for your string text?

Comment: not even if I use iframe or embed for viewing pdf?

Comment: @jeff I tried on tab but result is negative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull out the row id and the desired string first. Have the page display the string (outside the iframe), and then within the iframe, have it call another PHP page that pulls out the PDF content based on a given row id (i.e. in the query_string).

Comment: yes now its working ...my code is like : <div><div id='my-string'>some result</div><div id='my-blob'><iframe src='pdf.php'/></div></div>